# Controller throwing errors until data is loaded, even with a resolve

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

Good day everyone,

I have a simple html, routing, controller and service:

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="skillAmountLevelled() > 0">
   <label> Yep, there's more than 0. </label>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('levelCalculatorController', ['$scope', '$http', 'skillService', function ($scope, $http, skillService) {
skillService.getSkills().then(function (data) {
    $scope.skills = data;
}, function () {
    console.log("Error loading Skills");
});

$scope.skillAmountLevelled = function () {
    var skillsLevelledTotal = 0;
    var isLevelNotTooHigh = true;
    for (skillIndex = 0; skillIndex < $scope.skills.length; skillIndex++) {
        skillsLevelledTotal = skillsLevelledTotal + $scope.skills[skillIndex].timesLevelled;
    }

    return skillsLevelledTotal;
}
}]);
```

`$scope.skills[skillIndex].timesLevelled` is an int with the amount of times that skill has been levelled.

Service:

```
app.service('skillService', function ($http) {
    var getSkills = function () {
        return $http.get('Content/Data/skills.json').then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
         });
    };

    return {
         getSkills: getSkills
    }
});
```

Routing:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/levelCalculator", {
        templateUrl: "Content/Views/levelCalculator.html",
        controller: "levelCalculatorController",
        controllerAs: "levelCalculator",
        resolve: {
            skills: function (skillService) {
                return skillService.getSkills();
            }
        }
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

With all that set and done, it performs exactly as expected. It shows the text when there's more than 0 skills with a level in it. The problem I'm having is that it keeps throwing "cannot read property skills of undefined" errors on the `$scope.skillAmountLevelled` function at the `$scope.skills.length` line until the data has been loaded from the json.

I'm still a beginner in Angular and I expected the resolve in the routing to get rid of this, because it should get the skillService out of the way before loading the controller.

Did I mess up in my implementation or is it a simple matter of implementing an `if($scope.skills){}` in my `skillAmountLevelled`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you copy the full content of your controller? I asked because I can't see the closing part of the '[' and the controller function.

Comment: It's not the full controller, the full controller has a whole bunch of functions unrelated to this, so a missing bracket might have been uncareful copying on my part, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routing file :

```
resolve: {
    skills: function (skillService) {
        return skillService.getSkills();
    }
}
```

... injects a promise into your controller on load.

When the promise completes successfully, the resolve property is available to inject into your dedicated controller.
In other words, you don't have to `getSkills()` in your controller, as `skills` are already available in your controller function (using the same name as the resolve property).

```
app.controller('levelCalculatorController', function ($scope, $http, skillService, skills) {
    $scope.skills = skills;

    [...]
}
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Doing this I get bombarded with errors that skills is undefined.

Comment: Not forgetting 'skills' as your function params ? I mean, it's the basic point of using resolve(). See docs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

"the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess event is fired"

Comment: I'm an idiot and forgot to initialize skills in the controller. Thanks, this fixed it!

Comment: Welcome :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Try initing `$scope.skills = [];` this way before calling getSkills.